# Is it possible to call local storage in SSR Nuxt application middleware?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, middleware

I have a Nuxt app with this middleware

```
middleware(context) {
    const token = context.route.query.token;

    if (!token) {
        const result = await context.$api.campaignNewShare.createNewShare();
        context.redirect({'name': 'campaigns-new', 'query': {token: result.data.token}});
        local.storage.setKey(token, new DateTime().getTime());
    }
},
```

I need to store the token to the local storage but I am not sure if it is possible or safe.

Comment: You should probably use only [this plugin](https://github.com/nuxt-community/universal-storage-module) and never think about this question again.

Comment: Or even [this one](https://github.com/unjs/unstorage).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is impossible. localStorage is a browser part, but on SSR the code evaluates on the server-side. Using cookies is a good solution.

I recommend to use this module: https://github.com/nuxt-community/universal-storage-module

Comment: Cookies are not good solution. LoacalStorage has much more space to store data. Am I missing something?

Comment: I have a question. If I call `$storage.setLocalStorage(key, value)` in the middleware and then redirects to another location. Can I call localStorage.getItem('key') on this new location? I dont understand how this package handles the storages if they are not actually available like localStorage in middleware.

Comment: @Čamo I agree cookies are not the best solution. I believe there should be a SSR solution for authorisation based on auth tokens. Have you read this post https://auth.nuxtjs.org/api/options/